# How to get Base64-encoded data without padding?

Tags: java, clojure, base64, urlencode

I'm very new to Clojure. I don't have any experience with Java and its library functions. I wrote a function in clojure which returns Base64-encoded data using java.util.Base64/getUrlEncoder. My code looks like this:

```
user> (import java.util.Base64)
java.util.Base64
user> (let [encoder (Base64/getUrlEncoder)]
        (String. (.encode encoder (.getBytes "Hello StackOverflow"))))
"SGVsbG8gU3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw=="
```

As you can see, the output contains padding: two equals signs at the end. I don't want that padding.

I see that Java's Base64.Encoder class has [a 'withoutPadding()' method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#withoutPadding--) for this purpose, but I can't figure out how to use it in Clojure. I tried something like this:

```
user> (let [encoder (Base64/getUrlEncoder))]
        (doto (java.util.Base64/Encoder (.withoutPadding (String. (.encode encoder (.getBytes "Hello StackOverflow"))))))
```

but it didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Base64 outputs multiples of 4-bytes, if the input does not require that the output is padded with "=" characters, that is how Base64 works. It is possible to remove the "=" characters and sone decoders might accept that but not most. You could restore and deleted prior to decoding based on the Base64 length, but this is not recommended. Just leave the padding, that is the common practice.

Comment: to be clear, base64 is not an encryption method, it is an encoding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `withoutPadding` on the Encoder itself:

```
user> (import java.util.Base64)
java.util.Base64
user> (let [encoder (Base64/getUrlEncoder)]
        (String. (.encode encoder (.getBytes "Hello StackOverflow"))))
"SGVsbG8gU3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw=="
user> (let [encoder (.withoutPadding (Base64/getUrlEncoder))]
        (String. (.encode encoder (.getBytes "Hello StackOverflow"))))
"SGVsbG8gU3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdw"
```

Answer (score 0):

For **JAVA 21**, i used this code :

```java
Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(bytes)
```